# How is the Matrix website able to know the time of the client and show it in their video?

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video, video-processing

I recently visited the site:

https://thechoiceisyours.whatisthematrix.com/

and selecting any of the two pills will play a video showing the new Matrix movie trailer.

**Question:**
What intrigued me is the time shown in the video is always the same as the viewer's time.
 I know the browser can access user's time but am wondering how they were able to integrate it with the playing video in **realtime**?

Comment: Likely they generate it from a library of o'clocks - like your navigator knows to say "turn right"

Comment: They just serve a different video depending on the time. So depending on the time the user has a different video is loaded from the server.

Comment: So basically they have a different video for every minute of the day?

Comment: The video is being served in small chunks, interestingly mp4 and not HLS or DASH as far as I could see form a quick check - I would assume they just have multiple versions of the small chunk with the time, rather than of the whole video.